# Closed form for a sum involving Bernoulli numbers

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I need a closed form for the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2^{2n}-1)\pi^{2n}B_{2n} {2n+4 \choose m}x^{2n+4}}{(2n)!}$$
where $0<x<1$, $B_{2n}$ denotes Bernoulli numbers , $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and ${n \choose r}$ are the binomial coefficients.

I tried a code on Wolfram cloud but did not get any result:

```
Sum[(-1)^(n-1)*(2^(2n)-1)*Pi^(2n)*
  BernoulliB[2n]*Binomial[2n+4, m]*x^(2n+4)/(2n)!,
  {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

**Edit** I need a closed form for the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2^{2n}-1)\pi^{2n}B_{2n} {2n+4 \choose m} B(2n+5,m+1)}{(2n)!}$$
where $B_{2n}$ denotes Bernoulli numbers , $B(m,n)$ is the Beta function , $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and ${n \choose r}$ are the binomial coefficients.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you believe that a closed form for this expression exists? It does look like some sort of sum related to the Riemann zeta function....

Comment: @Pillsy Yes I indeed believe that a closed form expression for this exists.

Comment: Try setting $m$ to 0, 1, and 2, respectively, and add in the assumption $0<x<1$.

Comment: What is $m$? Is it an integer?

Comment: @Somos $m$ is a natural number.

Comment: @JimB Sorry I could not follow.

Comment: Try setting $m$ to 0 and add in the assumption $0<x<1$.  Then do the same thing for $m=1$ and $m=2$.  I don't think there's a closed-form solution for $m>2$.

Comment: @Max for example, `Assuming[{0 < x < 1},
Sum[(-1)^(n-1)*(2^(2n)-1)*Pi^(2n)*
  BernoulliB[2n]*Binomial[2n+4, 1]*x^(2n+4)/(2n)!,
  {n, 1, Infinity}]
]` gives $-\frac{1}{4} x^4 \csc ^2(\pi  x) \left(-4 \pi ^2 x^2+\pi ^2 x^2 \sin ^2(\pi    x) \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)+2 \pi  x \sin (2 \pi  x)+16 \pi    x \sin (\pi  x) \cos (\pi  x)-8 \pi  x \sin ^2(\pi  x) \cot \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)-\pi  x \sin ^3(\pi  x) \csc  ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)\right)$

Comment: @AsukaMinato Please also introduce $m$ and assume $m\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @AsukaMinato I believe your result simplifies to $\frac{1}{4} \pi  x^5 (\pi  x+5 \sin (\pi  x)) \sec ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)$.

Comment: m = 2, result is `(Pi*x^5*Sec[(Pi*x)/2]^2*(20*Sin[Pi*x] + Pi*x*(10 + Pi*x*Tan[(Pi*x)/2])))/8` , mma give up when m == 3.

Comment: @AsukaMinato What do you mean by "mma give up when $m==3$?"

Comment: @Max try `Assuming[{0 < x < 1},
Sum[(-1)^(n-1)*(2^(2n)-1)*Pi^(2n)*
  BernoulliB[2n]*Binomial[2n+4, 3]*x^(2n+4)/(2n)!,
  {n, 1, Infinity}]
] // FullSimplify` and you will know.

Comment: @AsukaMinato Ok thanks a lot

Comment: For $m = 3$, I think the sum is $\frac{1}{48} \pi  x^5 \sec ^4\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right) \left(2 \pi ^3 x^3+15 \left(\pi ^2 x^2+4\right) \sin (\pi  x)+\pi  \left(60-\pi ^2 x^2\right) x \cos (\pi  x)+60 \pi  x+30 \sin (2 \pi  x)\right)$, i.e. `1/48 π x^5 Sec[π x)/2]^4 (60 π x + 2 π^3 x^3 + π x (60 - π^2 x^2) Cos[π x] + 15 (4 + π^2 x^2) Sin[π x] + 30 Sin[2π x])`.

Comment: Please one question per post.